# Grouping large text data with respect to emoji in Python

Tags: python, grouping

I have 300MB opinion data which is stored in a file.

In those opinions there are 751 different emoji strings. How can I group those opinions with respect to emoji? For instance
'Smiley_emoji' list should includes all opinions that have smiley emoji.

what I thought is;

```
for opinion in opinionsArray:
    if smiley_emoji in opinion:
       smiley_emoji_arr.append(opinion)
    elif sad_emoji in opinion:
       sad_emoji_arr.append(opinion)
    elif other_emoji in opinion:
       other_emoji_arr.append(opinion)
    ....
```

And then print all those emoji and it's respective opinions.

I can be considered as a Python newbie. 
As I can't create 751 if/else statement and 751 different lists.
Is there a more convenient way to group those data with respect to emoji?

Thanks in advance

Edit : 
Emoji is a kind of string representation such as ; smiley_emoji, sad_emoji, etc. Data is stored in a txt file and each opinion is in line such as;
line1 includes opinion1 with an emoji, line2 includes opinion2 with an emoji etc.
I am looking for an efficient and smart way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Showing some data would be helpful.

Comment: what kind of file is the data stored in?  Are the emoji strings some kind of string representation of each emoji, or a picture?

Comment: If you have a list of all the emojis you can loop through them instead of having 751 `if` statements.

Comment: dictionaries be way handy

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
opinions = ['hello :)', 'world ;)']

emoji = {
    ':)': [],  # smile
    ';)': []   # wink
}

for i in opinions:
    for k, v in emoji.items():
        if k in i:
            v.append(i)
            break  # assuming opinions don't have multiple emoji
```

You would, however, probably build the `emoji` dictionary from a file of the possible strings.

As an aside, asking questions so narrowly tailored to your specific needs is not best practice. Try to break down your problem and think about how it generalizes. i.e., ask *programming* questions, not questions about a specific task.